# Calculation of the touching point of two circles given limited data

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I am trying to calculate the touching point of two circles. I have the following information.

Circle $1$:

- Centre $(h,k)$
- Radius $r_1$

Circle $2$:

- Point on Circumference $(x_1,y_1)$
- Radius $r_2$

From this I would like to calculate the centre point of circle $2$: $(s,r)$ and the point where they touch: $(x,y)$.

I have worked out that to find the second centre point I can express the formulas like this:

$$(x_1-s)^2+(y_1-r)^2=r_2^2$$

$$(s-h)^2+(r-k)^2=(r_1+r_2)^2$$

Unforunately my maths skills are not up to the task of solving these equations for $s$ and $r$, and ultimately for $x$ and $y$.

I would appreciate any help that can be provided.

Regards

Martin.

Comment: Are the circles supposed to be tangent, so there is only one point where they touch?  If not, I don't think there is enough information.  Even so, I believe there are two solutions.

Comment: Yes They are tangential.  I am looking to find that point of tangentiality.  I think there can only be one solution if it is tangential. - Martin.

Comment: @Isaac.  Thank you for help.  You've given me the answer I needed.  Regards Martin.

Comment: @Martin: please do not use answers to make comments. You should be able to comment on answers to your own questions even at low reputation.

Answer (score 1):

For the two equations you have, expand the squares on the left sides.  You'll have $s^2$ and $r^2$ on the left side in both equations.  Subtracting the two equations gives an equation that is linear in $s$ and $r$.  Solve the linear equation for one variable and substitute into one of your original two equations to solve for the other variable.  I believe that there are two solutions (by symmetry over the line through the known center and the known circumference point).

***edit***  Let me redefine your variables, then go through some of the algebra.  I'll continue to call the known center $(h,k)$ and the radius of that circle $r_1$ and the radius of the other circle $r_2$; I'll call the known point on the circumference of the other circle $(a,b)$, the desired point of tangency $(c,d)$, and the unknown center of the other circle $(m,n)$.  The system of equations you had, written in my variables, is:
$$\begin{align}
(a-m)^2+(b-n)^2&=r_2^2
\\
(m-h)^2+(n-k)^2&=(r_1+r_2)^2
\end{align}$$
We want to solve for $(m,n)$.  Expand the squares (use $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$) on the left sides of both equations:
$$\begin{align}
a^2-2am+m^2+b^2-2bn+n^2&=r_2^2
\\
m^2-2mh+h^2+n^2-2nk+k^2&=(r_1+r_2)^2
\end{align}$$
Subtract the two equations (I'm subtracting the first from the second):
$$(m^2-2mh+h^2+n^2-2nk+k^2)-(a^2-2am+m^2+b^2-2bn+n^2)=(r_1+r_2)^2-r_2^2$$
$$m(2a-2h)+n(2b-2k)+(h^2+k^2-a^2-b^2)=r_1^2+2r_1r_2$$
I've grouped the terms on the left side into $m$ times some constant, $n$ times some constant, and a constant term (only $m$ and $n$ are variables here); I'll continue to group terms in this way.  Solve for one of the variables ($m$):
$$\begin{align}
m(2a-2h)
&=r_1^2+2r_1r_2-n(2b-2k)-(h^2+k^2-a^2-b^2)
\\
&=(r_1^2+2r_1r_2-h^2-k^2+a^2+b^2)-n(2b-2k)
\end{align}$$
$$m=\frac{(r_1^2+2r_1r_2-h^2-k^2+a^2+b^2)-n(2b-2k)}{2a-2h}$$
Now, substitute this expression for $m$ in one of the two original equations (I'll use the first):
$$(a-\frac{(r_1^2+2r_1r_2-h^2-k^2+a^2+b^2)-n(2b-2k)}{2a-2h})^2+(b-n)^2=r_2^2$$
This is a (very messy) quadratic equation in $n$ (it can be written in the form $()n^2+()n+()=0$; $n$ is the only variable; the rest are constants).  While it's possible to continue to solve by hand, the symbolic manipulation is messy (though I can fill in more detail if necessary).  The two solutions for $n$ (note the $\pm$) that result are:

$n=\scriptstyle\frac{a^2 (b+k)-2 a h (b+k)+h^2 (b+k)+(b-k) \left(b^2-k^2+r_1^2+2 r_1r_2\right)\pm\sqrt{-(a-h)^2 \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-r_1^2\right) \left(a^2-2 a h+(b-k)^2+(h-r_1-2 r_2) (h+r_1+2 r_2)\right)}}{2 \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2\right)}$

The next step would be to take this, put it back into the expression for $m$ to get two values of $m$.  Here are the results I get using Mathematica:

$(m,n)=$
$\begin{matrix}\scriptstyle{\left(
  \frac{1}{2 (a-h) \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2\right)}
  \left(\scriptstyle{\begin{align}
    a^4&-2 a^3 h+2 a h^3-h^2 \left(h^2+(b-k)^2\right)+a^2 (b-k)^2+(a-h)^2 r_1 \left(r_1+2 r_2\right)\\
    &+b \sqrt{-(a-h)^2 \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-r_1^2\right) \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-\left(r_1+2 r_2\right){}^2\right)}\\
    &-k \sqrt{-(a-h)^2 \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-r_1^2\right) \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-\left(r_1+2 r_2\right){}^2\right)}
  \end{align}}\right)\right.},\\ \quad\quad\scriptstyle{\left.
  \frac{\left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2\right) (b+k)+(b-k) r_1 \left(r_1+2 r_2\right)-\sqrt{-(a-h)^2 \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-r_1^2\right) \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-\left(r_1+2 r_2\right){}^2\right)}}{2 \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2\right)}\right)}\end{matrix}$

or $(m,n)=$
$\begin{matrix}\scriptstyle{\left(
  \frac{1}{2 (a-h) \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2\right)}
  \left(\scriptstyle{\begin{align}
    a^4&-2 a^3 h+2 a h^3-h^2 \left(h^2+(b-k)^2\right)+a^2 (b-k)^2+(a-h)^2 r_1 \left(r_1+2 r_2\right)\\
    &-b \sqrt{-(a-h)^2 \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-r_1^2\right) \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-\left(r_1+2 r_2\right){}^2\right)}\\
    &+k \sqrt{-(a-h)^2 \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-r_1^2\right) \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-\left(r_1+2 r_2\right){}^2\right)}
  \end{align}}\right)\right.},\\ \quad\quad\scriptstyle{\left.
  \frac{\left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2\right) (b+k)+(b-k) r_1 \left(r_1+2 r_2\right)+\sqrt{-(a-h)^2 \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-r_1^2\right) \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2-\left(r_1+2 r_2\right){}^2\right)}}{2 \left((a-h)^2+(b-k)^2\right)}\right)}\end{matrix}$

Since we know the two circles are tangent at the point $(c,d)$, the point $(c,d)$ is on the line connecting the centers of the circles and $\frac{r_1}{r_1+r_2}$ of the way from $(h,k)$ to $(m,n)$, so $$(c,d)=\left(\frac{r_2}{r_1+r_2}h+\frac{r_1}{r_1+r_2}m,\frac{r_2}{r_1+r_2}k+\frac{r_1}{r_1+r_2}n\right).$$

Mathematica isn't generating any nice simplification of that expression with $m$ and $n$ substituted in, so I'll stop here.

Comment: Hello @Isaac, Thank you for your answer, unfortunately the mathematical solution you suggest is beyond my skill level, hence my posting here.  I am from a non mathematical background.  Regards Martin.

Comment: @Martin: I added a bunch more detail, but about a third to half way into the problem, the algebra gets pretty nasty, so I went to using Mathematica.  The expressions for a final answer are sufficiently messy that I didn't actually include the expressions.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This is not entirely correct since the radius of the second circle is given.**

If I'm reading your question correctly, your second circle is not uniquely determined. Here are some examples:

[image: non-uniqueness]

The point on the circumference of your (non-unique) second circle is labeled A, but there are infinitely many circles through A that are tangent to the first circle (centered at *Q*).

Comment: But we are given the radius of the circle that passes through A.  I think that is enough to define it as one of two circles, one "each side" of A.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for pointing that out